# Returning large collectionresult set from WCF

Tags: json, xml, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I am trying to return large result set from WCF service. Large result set would probably have approax 500K records and each record will have 150 columns.

I know by configuring WCF bindings we can return large result set. But I am not sure about the limit. I tried this scenario but got error to increase the limit of "maxItemsInObjectGraph" property even I set the value as "2147483647" of this property. I googled the alternate options and found that this can be achieved with messageEncoding and transferMode property of Binding. I tried with "Mtom" and "StreamResponse" but I am not sure how it is working?

I also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789938/returning-large-collections-from-wcf-serivce) link but dont want to make pagination as my client wants data in one go.

**So Conclusion is:**

```
1. Can we return large result set from WCF? Or Does the use of WCF best to return large result set or I need to move to different way like WebAPI?
2. StreamResponse should work like returning results in chunck I guess but after implementation, I don't think it is working as I am getting result altogether.
```

Your inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can return large object sets from WCF service. WebAPI or other .NET service framework doesn't have advantage considering transferring a lot of data.
2. StreamResponse is the best choice for you. It transfers message portion by portion, so that you don't have all your 500K records on the wire at one moment. It's a transport layer option, hence for client it seems like he got the whole message at once. You can manage that portion size by editing MaxBufferSize property of your binding.
   To minimize the size of data you can also compress it using BinaryMessageEncoding.

   ```
   <customBinding>
   <binding name="primaryBinding" openTimeout="00:01:00"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
     <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     </binaryMessageEncoding>
     <httpsTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000" 
                     maxBufferSize="6000000" maxBufferPoolSize="12000000" />          
   </binding>
   ```